# Why woocommerce need both consumer key and secret to access api?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I learn to use woocommerce api, I notice that certain access requires both consumer key and secret like below (source: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API).

```
https://local.wordpress.dev/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?consumer_key=XXXX&consumer_secret=XXXX
```

I feel puzzled, is it really safe to give both key and secret over the wire? For authentication purpose, shouldn't sending the key be enough and secret should stay? What is the reason behind that?

BTW, I test with a few failed logins and the URL is recorded in the log with key and secret in plain text!

So is there any way of authentication that avoids sending the secret?